# container crashes without obvious reason or error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run container with these dockerfiles:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_URL_DEPTS=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/depts_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL_DEPTS=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/depts_test
    depends_on:
      - users-db

  users-db:
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y netcat && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Waiting for postgres...'

while ! nc -z users-db 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo 'PostgreSQL started'

python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

The Postgres container works just fine but the `users` service exits out as soon I spin it off.
Normally, I'd bash into the container and look into logs but the fact that the container crashes immediately rules this out as an option.

What can I do ?

Comment: `docker logs <image ID>` show any logs? If you don't have the image ID, `docker ps -a` should show exited image IDs.

Comment: @Emma  Wow ... Docker has its own logs ! It spat out the error. Thank you, thank you, thank you ! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'm gonna tick it for you.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, the log content will also be written to stdout.

Comment: Jest a little correction to what Emma wrote `docker logs <container ID>` not `image ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Shmuel for the correction.

You can view stdout, stderr of docker containers by

```
docker logs <container ID>
```

Alternatively, as @David Maze pointed out, stdout/stderr is printed out on console if you `docker-compose` without `-d` option.

For more about docker logs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: You should get a medal for mentioning "not to use the `-d` flag" !

Answer (score 1):

Try tty: true for users in docker-compose file

```
users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    tty: true
    .....
```

Comment: Great to know !

Comment: explanation please